# Render several jQuery objects at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to improve the performance of my application. At the moment I'm rendering several jQuery objects one at the time.

Example:

```
$.each(objects, function(i,v))
{
     // Rendering each object
     object.data('hi', v.value).appendTo('body');
});
```

Instead I would like to do something like:

```
var array = new Array();
$.each(objects, function(i,v))
{
     // Storing each object
     array[i] = object.data('hi', v.value);
});
// Rendering all objects at once
array.appendTo('body');
```

Is it possible to achive what I'm asking for?

Comment: I don't see a big difference between the approaches. Btw, it would need to be `$(array).appendTo('body')`

Comment: Unless I'm really wrong, what's the difference?

Comment: @Bergi & MelanciaUK, There's a significant difference, because DOM manipulation is quite expensive and should be limited to minium. Inserting nodes in a loop may trigger many reflow/repaint events, so it's better to keep these nodes somewhere outside the DOM tree and append them all at once.

Comment: There´s a significant performance difference between rendering all at once and rendering one at the time.

Comment: The latter approach would do a loop through the `array` just as well - only there are no additional operations in between the DOM insertions. Both approaches should only do a reflow/repaint when all DOM manipulation is done, so it won't affect your performance noticably (unless your array is just too huge). To do ensure "all-at-once", put them in a `DocumentFragment` and append that.

Comment: @pawel do you know if I can do this in a good way? I need to append a data variable so I won´t be able to put it all in a string.

Comment: @Bergi sure, and the answer posted at the moment would add these elements using a loop just as well. `DocumentFragment` is the way to go, or even `var temp = $('<div />');' and then `temp.append` in the loop, `temp.appendTo('body')` after the loop. This would create an additional element, but unwrapping it would throw us back to a loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `DocumentFragment` as suggested by @Bergi:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
$.each(objects, function(i,v))
{
     // Storing each object
     object.data('hi', v.value).appendTo( fragment );
});
// Rendering all objects at once
$('body').append( fragment );
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4kTKG/1/